# Can set_parameter_options be added to the trajectory class?

Tags: openmdao

For the Dymos problems I work with, I have code that adds states, controls, etc. in bulk and then use the `set_XXX_options()` method to specify specific parameter values (e.g. `opt=True`). This is easy for Dymos phases, because each phase has a `add_XXX()` method and an associated `set_XXX_options()` method. However, the `trajectory.add_parameter()` method does an associated `trajectory.set_parameter_options()` method.

Is there a reason the `set_parameter_options()` method is not available for trajectory objects? Can it be added as a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good point and there's no reason we can't add this method, and we should for API consistency.

In the mean time, you can access the `parameter_options` dictionary after add_parameter to change settings.  For instance,

```
traj.add_parameter('foo', ...)
traj.parameter_options['foo']['opt'] = True
```

I'll add an issue to make this a part of the API.